# Pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo para el condicional

Tags: subjuntivo, condicional

Siempre se usa *si + pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo* para empezar la cláusula condicional. Como por ejemplo *si tuviera dinero, si fuera rico, si pudiera,* etc.

¿Por qué estas expresiones se interpretan en el presente? Por ejemplo, *si fuera rico = pero no lo soy*.

Si bien *fuera* es pretérito, ¿por qué se interpreta como presente?

Answer (score 4):

No se usa siempre, solo en oraciones hipotéticas (o condicionales irreales o potenciales, según terminología).

En general, si la acción expresada dentro de la cláusula *sí* se considera una verdadera posibilidad, va marcada en el tiempo esperado y en el indicativo. El español antiguo podía usar otros tiempos para condiciones futuras como lo hace hoy en día el portugués, pero este uso no ha sobrevivido en el presente, así que se usa siempre el indicativo si queda una posibilidad de veracidad:

- Si me acompañarás (pero no sé nada de tus planes), viajaré a China.
- Si tengo tiempo (y puede que lo tenga), iré a la tienda (en el caso de tenerlo, pero aún no tengo claro si lo tendré o no).
- Si hablo con mi madre por la mañana (a veces ocurre, a veces no), no la llamo por la noche (dependerá de lo que he hecho por la mañana).
- Si tenían dinero, salían de copas (aquí, nos referimos a algo habitual: a veces el dinero estaba, a veces no, y entonces a veces salían, a veces no).
- Si lo rompió mi hijo (y no lo sé), te compraré otro.

Pero cuando la acción en la cláusula *sí* denota algo definitivamente irreal, sin ocurrir ni posibilidad de ocurrir, los tiempos utilizados se suelen retroceder. Es decir, se usa el imperfecto para referirse al presente, y el pluscuamperfecto para referirse al pretérito (perfecto e imperfecto), aunque no es imposible encontrar el imperfecto para referirse a acciones pretéritas. Lo mismo ocurre, curiosamente, en el inglés. Ya que se trata de algo que no ha acaecido, se usa el subjuntivo:

- Si hubieran/hubiesen tenido dinero (pero no lo tenían), habrían salido de copas (así que no salieron).
- Si tuviera tiempo (pero no lo tengo), iría a la tienda (así que no iré).

Comment: Hay unas construcciones extrañas: *si me acompañarás*, es raro ver el futuro en ambas cláusulas. ¿Es natural? Pues nunca lo he usado, no me suena idiomático. Al igual que *si tenían dinero*, es como armar en pasado ambas cláusulas, pero tiene sentido.

Comment: @ustanak sí, requieren un contexto particular (sobre todo con el futuro, porque para estar en la cláusula —que sepa yo—  tendría que interpretar más bien con su significado especulativo). Solo los puse como ejemplos de la diversidad de posibilidades, no necesariamente como algo que se escucharía con gran frecuencia.

Comment: Claro, porque de verdad hallo bastante anormal usar el futuro en ambas cláusulas. Normalmente lo que se usa es la forma simple y el futuro en la otra clásula para predecir el resultado de una acción.

Comment: Ayer oí a un mexicano decir "Sin mí, no hubiera blues en México. No lo conocieran" (Jorge Bartiz) ¿Es esta misma regla?

Answer (score 1):

En inglés se dice: if I were a rich man.  Es la misma forma.
"Were" es un subjuntivo pretérito.  La pregunta no tiene nada que ver con el inglés, pero el hecho que aparezca en más de un idioma es interesante.